# Exception in thread java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

I faced an error(as mentioned in the title), because I'm trying to use the scanner class to input a string. I've searched through google and I noted that a lot of people face the same issues, but none of the suggested solutions seem to work for me, hence I'm asking it here. My code is as such:

```
public void displayPrice() {
        System.out.println("You need to be above 18 to continue. Do you wish to continue? Yes/No");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        in.nextLine();
        String obj;
        obj = in.nextLine();
        if (obj.equals("Yes")) {
            getPrice();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enjoy your day.");
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `getPrice()` method do?

Comment: why the first `nextLine()` ?

Comment: Your code is little confusing as you have not mentioned the function of getPrice() and why you have used in.nextLine(); two times. Please edit it so, that we can understand it properly

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sample.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PriceList {

    public static void displayPrice() {
        System.out.println("You need to be above 18 to continue. Do you wish to continue? Yes/No");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        in.nextLine();
        String obj;
        obj = in.nextLine();
        if (obj.equals("Yes")) {
            getPrice();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enjoy your day.");
        }
        in.close();
    }

    private static void getPrice() {

        System.out.println("Enjoy your day.");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayPrice();
    }

}
```

It does not caused any issue for me. The following is my output.

```
You need to be above 18 to continue. Do you wish to continue? Yes/No
Yes
YEs
Enjoy your day.
```

But Scanner is used twice by you. It can be modified as shown below:

```
String obj = in.nextLine();
    if (obj.equals("Yes")) {
        getPrice();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enjoy your day.");
    }
```

But Scanner can cause issue so always I use BufferedReader

```
package com.sample.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PriceList {

    public static void displayPrice() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("You need to be above 18 to continue. Do you wish to continue? Yes/No");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String obj;
        try {
            obj = br.readLine();
            if (obj.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                getPrice();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enjoy your day.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        }
    }

    private static void getPrice() {
        System.out.println("It costs $10");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        displayPrice();
    }

}
```

Comment: And where is the answer?!!